# Passing parameters while posting status to Twitter using Terminal with CURL

Tags: post, curl, terminal, twitter

How to pass additional parameters to this twitter update api by using curl from terminal?

http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml

Say I need to pass replyto user id as given in the documentation. Although I could simply append @username before the message, I need user id based and @user_id didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to simply append it to the url.

http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?in_reply_to_status_id=12345